# VMWare How to share the connection between a NAT and a host-only network?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware, nat

I have 2 VMs running. (On Ubuntu 14.04)

The first one has 2 network adaptater (NAT and host only)

The second one has 1 network adaptater (host only).

The first can ping google.com.

The second one can ping the host only interface of the first one.

How can the second one be able to ping google too ? (Like how can the first VM share the internet connexion between the NAT and the host only interface?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to configure Host 1, with the 2 NICs, as a router, and ensure that Host 2 is using Host 1 as it's gateway. There are many how-to's including on this site.

EDIT: For example, [How to make a pc act as a router on some port](https://superuser.com/questions/677773/how-to-make-a-pc-act-as-a-router-on-some-port/677791#677791)